# Is there any terminal viewer of CHM files in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, chm

I did not manage to find anyone. 
I have a problem that I need to access my CHM files over network and over VPN which makes the requirement rather slow with the normal CHM viewer. 
Therefore, I thought about terminal viewer of the format.

There are html viewers of terminal, elinks/lynx, but none of them can maintain chm features such searches in different environments.
The standard of CHM viewers is h.exe in Windows. Anything that can reach even near it with search capabilities would be nice in terminal.

Is there any terminal viewer of CHM files in Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried using vim? Also, I'm not that familiar with CHM files but it looks like they are in HTML format. If so, you could always use something like `sed -e 's/<[^>]*>//g' filename` to print it out and clean up the formatting.

Comment: Your approach does not maintain the search features of chm in different environments.

Comment: What viewer are you currently using. I can take a look at it and see what you are taking about?

Comment: @mchid h.exe is the standard found in Windows. There are several CHM viewers but I would like to have viewer with search capabilities in different environments in terminal.

Comment: Hh.exe is included with a standard wine install.

Comment: @mchid Yes, but the topic is not about h.exe or Hh.exe but about terminal viewer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a perfect viewer but a workaround.

1. Install `archmage`: a CHM(Compiled HTML) Decompressor,
2. extract the file
3. open the output in a non-graphical (text-mode) web browser, e.g. `lynx`:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository universe
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install archmage

   sudo apt-get install lynx-cur

   archmage file.chm output_dir

   lynx output_dir
   ```

---

Another extract tool is `extract_chmLib`, also in the universe repository:

```
sudo apt-get install libchm-bin
extract_chmLib file.chm output_dir
```

Comment: Thank you for illustrating preliminary stage. Elinks may be better. I am mostly interested in maintaining chm functions i.e. Searches in diff environments.

Comment: @Masi Lynx does allows searching.  Does its search capability somehow not meet your needs?

Comment: Yes, it does not. I want to focus the search like in h.exe: section display first (probably build by searching headings/titles of sections) and separately search within each section. I have not been able build such a frontend with Lynx, since I cannot customize it.